# NpgSql and PostgreSQL 12.4 - Only getting the cursor name from data reader instead of the rows of data

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I'm trying to pull back data from PostgreSQL using a data reader. Each time I run my code the only value returned is the name of the refcursor.

[image: There is only one row returned when there should be 3. The single value returned is the name of the refcursor - 'city_cursor'. Where are the city rows I'm expecting?]

I created the following to illustrate my problem. I'm using NpgSql .net core 3.1 aginst a PostgreSQL 12.4 database. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a simple table of cities with a function that is supposed to return the list of cities stored in the tblcities table.

```
CREATE TABLE public.tblcities
(
    cityname character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    state character varying(2) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT tblcities_pkey PRIMARY KEY (cityname)
);

INSERT INTO public.tblcities(cityname, state) VALUES ('San Francisco','CA');
INSERT INTO public.tblcities(cityname, state) VALUES ('San Diego','CA');
INSERT INTO public.tblcities(cityname, state) VALUES ('Los Angeles','CA');

CREATE OR REPLACE Function getcities() RETURNS REFCURSOR
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    ref refcursor := 'city_cursor';
BEGIN

    OPEN ref FOR
    select *
    from tblcities;
    
    Return ref;
END;
$BODY$;
```

The following is the .net code.

```
public static void GetCities()
    {
        using (var cn = new NpgsqlConnection(dbconn_string))
        {
            if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                cn.Open();

            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "getcities";
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //There is only one row returned when there should be 3.
                    //The single value returned is the name of the refcursor - 'city_cursor'
                    //Where are the city rows I'm expecting?
                    var value1 = dr[0]; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, rather than returning a refcursor, you generally return the data itself - change the function to have `RETURNS TABLE` instead of `RETURNS REFCURSOR` ([see the docs for more details](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)). If you return a cursor to the client, the client must then perform another roundtrip to fetch the results for that cursor, whereas when returning a table directly no additional round-trip is needed.

This is one of the main reasons Npgsql doesn't automatically "dereference" cursors - lots of people coming from other databases write functions returning cursors, when in reality doing that is very rarely necessary.

For some discussions around this, see https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1785 and https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/438.